# Spring RestTemplate Parse Custom Error Response

Tags: rest, spring-mvc

Given a REST service call

http://acme.com/app/widget/123

returns:

```
<widget>
  <id>123</id>
  <name>Foo</name>
  <manufacturer>Acme</manufacturer>
</widget>
```

This client code works:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
XStreamMarshaller xStreamMarshaller = new XStreamMarshaller();
xStreamMarshaller.getXStream().processAnnotations(
    new Class[] { 
        Widget.class,
        ErrorMessage.class
    });

HttpMessageConverter<?> marshallingConverter = new MarshallingHttpMessageConverter(
    xStreamMarshaller, xStreamMarshaller);

List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters = new ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>();
    converters.add(marshallingConverter);

restTemplate.setMessageConverters(converters);

Widget w = restTemplate.getForObject(
    "http://acme.com/app/widget/{id}", Widget.class, 123L);
```

However, calling http://acme.com/app/widget/456 returns:

```
<error>
    <message>Widget 456 does not exist</message>
    <timestamp>Wed, 12 Mar 2014 10:34:37 GMT</timestamp>
</error>
```

but this client code throws an Exception:

```
Widget w = restTemplate.getForObject(
    "http://acme.com/app/widget/{id}", Widget.class, 456L);

org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 404 Not Found
```

I tried:

```
try {
    Widget w = restTemplate.getForObject(
       "http://acme.com/app/widget/{id}", Widget.class, 456L);
}
catch (HttpClientErrorException e) {
    ErrorMessage errorMessage = restTemplate.getForObject(
       "http://acme.com/app/widget/{id}", ErrorMessage.class, 456L);

   // etc...
}
```

The second invocation just threw another HttpClientErrorException, plus it does not feel right calling the service twice.

Is there a way to call the service once and parse the response into a Widget on success and an ErrorMessage when not found?

Comment: I'm not sure why you are concerned about getting the exact error message from the XML response when it's effectively the same as the HTTP 404 - not found. Just catch the 404 and throw a new exception or generate your own message, etc.

Comment: If this custom message is successfully parsed, I know that the widget is not found vs the service is down or the wrong URL is being called for the service.

Comment: Fair enough, although 'service down' should be a different code (500).  I'd start reading the source for RestTemplate at this point..., are you sure the HTTP body is not being stored somewhere in the `HttpClientErrorException`?

Comment: You can visit bellow thread. It has full working code with description:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51805956/3073945

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Following from my comment, I checked the [`HttpClientErrorException` JavaDoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/client/HttpClientErrorException.html) and it does support both setting/getting the `statusText` as well as the `responseBody`. However they are optional and RestTemplate may not populate them - you'll need to try something like:

```
try {
    Widget w = restTemplate.getForObject(
       "http://acme.com/app/widget/{id}", Widget.class, 456L);
}
catch (HttpClientErrorException e) {
    String responseBody = e.getResponseBodyAsString();
    String statusText = e.getStatusText();
    // log or process either of these...
    // you'll probably have to unmarshall the XML manually (only 2 fields so easy)
}
```

If they are both empty/null then you may have to extend the RestTemplate class involved and populate those fields yourself and/or raise a Jira issue on the Spring site.

Comment: This sounded promising, but HttpClientErrorException is not thrown. Rather, I get org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'com.acme.ErrorMessage' to required type 'com.acme.Widget' which does not have the response body. I'll take a look at extending RestTemplate. Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: Your original question stated "but this client code throws an Exception:" - a HttpClientErrorException. Has something changed? I was suggesting that when this exception is thrown you deal with it in there - maybe my code was misleading.

Comment: @PaulCroarkin did you ever find a solution to deserializing the error body?

Comment: I have the same issue. In the API service I return an ApiError object which has error-code (e.g.: 423) and error-message (e.g.: access denied) as fields. When executed from the browser it returns the JSON message in response correctly, however when I call the same using restTemplate.postForObject it throws HttpClientErrorException with the right error code, but not the error-message.

Answer (score 8):

You can also create an object from Error response body if you like:

```
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
String errorResponse = ex.getResponseBodyAsString();

MyClass obj = om.readValue(errorResponse, MyClass.class);
```

Comment: Isn't the Jackson `ObjectMapper` about JSON, not XML ??  The question is about XML, not JSON.

Answer (score 2):

As you already catch the HttpClientErrorException object, it should allows you to easily extract useful information about the error and pass that to the caller.

For example:

```
try{
    <call to rest endpoint using RestTemplate>
} catch(HttpClientErrorException e){
    HttpStatus statusCode = e.getStatusCode();
    String body = e.getResponseBodyAsString();
}
```

IMO if one needs to further de-serialize the error message `body` into some relevant object, that can be handled somewhere outside of the catch statement scope.

Answer (score 1):

I too have found this a disturbing change in the Spring library. You used to be able to throw a ResponseStatusException and pass it the HttpStatus code and a custom message and then catch the HttpClientErrorException and simply print getMessage() to see the custom error. This no longer works. In order for me to print the custom error, I had to capture the ResponseBody as a String, getResponseBodyAsString on the HttpClientErrorException. Then I needed to parse this as a String doing some pretty hokey substring manipulation. Doing this strips out the information from the ResponseBody and gives the message sent by my server. The code to do this follows:

```
String message = hce.getResponseBodyAsString();
int start, end;
start =  message.lastIndexOf(":", message.lastIndexOf(",")-1) + 2;
end = message.lastIndexOf(",") -1;
message = message.substring(start, end);
System.out.println(message);
```

When I test this using ARC or Postman, they can display the correct message after I add server.error.include-message=always to my application.properties file on the server. I am not sure what method they are using to extract the message but that would be nice to know.