# Exception propogation

Tags: java

How do I propogate an exception thrown in a call to a downstream service to the caller method?

I have a service that calculates something and throws an exception in case of error:

```
{
  "timestamp": "2019-03-12T08:21:05.316+0000",
  "status": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "message": "VAKUUTUSVUOSI.MAKSUEHTO is null or not numeric. Can't be added to due date.",
  "path": "/rules/yk32/deducePaymentDueDate"
}
```

But the calling service displays this exception:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2019-03-12T08:30:22.912+0000",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "500 null",
    "path": "/calculation/annual/payment"
}
```

How do I get the caller method also to display the message that the service throws  "/rules/yk32/deducePaymentDueDate" instead of "Internal Server Error"?

**Calling method:**

```
LocalDate paymentDueDate = ykServiceAdapter.yk32DeducePaymentDueDate(requestDTO);
```

**Calling function in the ykServiceadapter:**

```
public LocalDate yk32DeducePaymentDueDate(Yk32RequestDTO requestDTO) {
    ResponseEntity<LocalDate> re;
    HttpEntity<?> entity = new HttpEntity<>(requestDTO);
    try {
        re = getRestTemplate().exchange(
                buildServiceUrl(externalServiceConfig, RULE_YK32, DEDUCE_PAYMENT_DUEDATE),
                HttpMethod.POST, entity,
                new ParameterizedTypeReference<LocalDate>() {
                });
        return re.getBody();

    } catch (HttpClientErrorException ex) {
        if (HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.equals(ex.getStatusCode())) {
            return null;
        } else {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: public LocalDate yk32DeducePaymentDueDate(Yk32RequestDTO requestDTO) throws Exception try this

Comment: Looks like the exception is being manipulated to set the message to Status somewhere up in the process

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Resttemplate exception handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38093388/spring-resttemplate-exception-handling)

Answer (score 1):

You're working on two separate contexts, via `HTTP`.

What that means is the `Exception` generated by `yk32DeducePaymentDueDate` is *transformed* to an `HTTP 500` response, which **might** mean the `Exception` message is used as response body.

Obviously, being that the original `Exception` gets lost during the `HTTP` call, `RestTemplate` is only able to create an `HttpClientErrorException` based on the `HTTP` status code

```
HttpClientErrorException.BadRequest
HttpClientErrorException.Conflict
HttpClientErrorException.Forbidden
HttpClientErrorException.Gone
HttpClientErrorException.MethodNotAllowed
HttpClientErrorException.NotAcceptable
HttpClientErrorException.NotFound
HttpClientErrorException.TooManyRequests
HttpClientErrorException.Unauthorized
HttpServerErrorException.InternalServerError
HttpServerErrorException.NotImplemented
...
```

In your case the instantiated `Exception` is

```
public static class InternalServerError extends HttpServerErrorException {
    InternalServerError(String statusText, HttpHeaders headers, byte[] body, @Nullable Charset charset) {
        super(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, statusText, headers, body, charset);
    }
}
```

---

Only the `Exception` message might be recovered, if it has been transmitted in the response body.

You might want to look into a custom `ResponseErrorHandler`, where you can inspect the full `HTTP` response and react accordingly.