# RestTemplate get body with ResourceAccessException

Tags: java, spring, error-handling, http-post, resttemplate

I'm sending API and receiving status code 400 with body I need to parse

When working with [RestTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38093388/spring-resttemplate-exception-handling) I failed to parse response:

```
try {
     ResponseEntity<ResponseVO> response = restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.POST, request, ResponseVO.class);
} catch(HttpStatusCodeException e){
     // not catch
     String errorpayload = e.getResponseBodyAsString();
}  catch (RestClientException e) {  
    // catch without body
}
```

Also With adding error handlers (default and specific) suggested I always get a `ResourceAccessException` which isn't catch by `HttpClientErrorException` and doesn't include body/headers data

How can I still get body/headers in that case? must I use alternatives to RestTemplate ?

Moreover, how can I return to context of request when I'm in caught exception inside `handleError`:

> ```
>  public void handleError(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue I was using interceptor which read my body already,

Changed RestTemplate to using [BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/client/BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory.html) I can now re-read my body

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(new BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory()));
```

> Using this wrapper allows for multiple reads of the response body.

Comment: Could you please add more details how do you get the body on BadRequest error for example?