# I want to return status code of 400 instead of 500 about unhandled exceptions, globally

Tags: spring, spring-boot, exception, http-status-code-400, http-status-code-500

I am trying to make `500 Internal Server Error` to `400 Bad Request` in every cases.

This is my package structure for exceptions.

[image: Directory image]

For example, `ConflictExeption` looks like this.

```java
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CONFLICT)
public class ConflictException extends ApiException {
    public ConflictException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }

    public ConflictException() {
        this("Conflict Exception.");
    }
}
```

```java
public class ApiException extends RuntimeException {
    public ApiException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

```java
public class UserEmailInUseException extends ConflictException{

    public static final String MESSAGE = "Desired email is already in use.";

    public UserEmailInUseException() {
        super(MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

Below is my simple service code.

```java
@Service
public class UsersService {
    @Transactional
        public UserInfoResponseDto signUp(UserSignupRequestDto requestDto) {
            if (usersRepository.findByEmail(requestDto.getEmail()).isPresent()) throw new 
                UserEmailInUseException();
        return new UserInfoResponseDto(usersRepository.save(requestDto.toEntity()));

    }

}
```

`UserEmailInUseException` extends `ConflictException`.

In my case, 500 error occurs when some violations are made while making transaction with MariaDB.

Simply put, I just want to return status code of 400 instead of 500, where exception is not handled.

Thanks in advance!

Also, I've tried this example below, and it seems to send 500..
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38093388/spring-resttemplate-exception-handling)

Comment: I've thought about covering each method in service codes with try-catch block, but personally I think this will make my code really dirty,.

Comment: You showed BadRequestException but you present code using UserEmailInUseException and ConflictException that have no source that makes it harder to answer.

Comment: @AleksanderLech Done!

Comment: Doing this probably a bad idea. You should be fixing your server code so it avoids or handles exceptions properly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class RestErrorHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler
    @ResponseStatus(BAD_REQUEST)
    Exception handleUnhandledException(Exception e) {
        return e;
    }
}
```

Comment: this will interpret all the exceptions as bad request

Comment: The snippet is to get the idea of how to approach it, and not to give the ideal and final solution, so I don't get why it was downvoted...

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are mapping it to `CONFLICT` instead of `BAD_REQUEST`. Have you tried the following annotation setting?

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
```

If you don't want to change existing `ConflictException` try to introduce a new base exception as follows:

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
public class BadRequestException extends ApiException {
    // [...]
}
```