# How to print complete error message when logging an exception generated by RestTemplate?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, error-handling, resttemplate

We have a Spring-Boot (2.3.10.RELEASE) based application which calls many REST APIs using `RestTemplate`.

In case, any REST API returns any 4xx or 5xx HTTP error code along with message body, complete message body is not getting logged.

Here is a minimum reproducible example:

```java
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

@Slf4j
public class RestTemplateTest {

    @Test
    void shouldPrintErrorForRestTemplate() {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        try {
            restTemplate.getForEntity("http://hellosmilep.free.beeceptor.com/error/notfound", String.class);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Error calling REST API", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
10:28:11.347 [main] ERROR com.smilep.java.webapp.RestTemplateTest - Error calling REST API
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$NotFound: 404 Not Found: [{
  "glossary": {
    "title": "example glossary",
    "GlossDiv": {
      "title": "S",
      "GlossList": {
        "GlossEntry": {
          "ID": "SGML",
          "SortAs": "SGML",
          "Glo... (593 bytes)]
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException.create(HttpClientErrorException.java:113)
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:184)
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:125)
    at org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler.handleError(ResponseErrorHandler.java:63)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:780)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:672)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForEntity(RestTemplate.java:340)
    at com.smilep.java.webapp.RestTemplateTest.shouldPrintErrorForRestTemplate(RestTemplateTest.java:15)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:686)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:212)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:208)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:137)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:71)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:248)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$5(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:226)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:199)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:132)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
```

You can notice response message is truncated with `"Glo... (593 bytes)]` in above stack trace. How to log the complete error response body?

I know I can do something like below to print the error response body but it will be too much of boilerplate code to be added in many classes (and also in other applications).

```java
if(e instanceof HttpClientErrorException) {
    log.error("response body : " + ((HttpClientErrorException) e).getResponseBodyAsString());
}
```

1. Is there any way by which logging `Exception` object would log complete error response message body instead of truncating with `... (593 bytes)]`?
2. Is there some default size limit in java after which it truncates any message in error log? If yes, how to change it?

**Update :**

After jccampanero's answer, I had raised [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/27552) issue with Spring team to make this logging message size limit configurable. They have removed the limit altogether. This change should be available in some future version of Spring.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[By default](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/b595dc1dfad9db534ca7b9e8f46bb9926b88ab5a/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.java#L138), `RestTemplate` uses [`DefaultErrorHandler`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/b595dc1dfad9db534ca7b9e8f46bb9926b88ab5a/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/client/DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java#L53) for processing errors.

In the implementation of this class, the different `handleError` methods - see for instance [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/b595dc1dfad9db534ca7b9e8f46bb9926b88ab5a/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/client/DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java#L165-L192) - rely on the [`getErrorMessage` method](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/b595dc1dfad9db534ca7b9e8f46bb9926b88ab5a/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/client/DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java#L128-L163):

```java
/**
  * Return error message with details from the response body, possibly truncated:
  * <pre>
  * 404 Not Found: [{'id': 123, 'message': 'my very long... (500 bytes)]
  * </pre>
  */
private String getErrorMessage(
    int rawStatusCode, String statusText, @Nullable byte[] responseBody, @Nullable Charset charset) {


  String preface = rawStatusCode + " " + statusText + ": ";
  if (ObjectUtils.isEmpty(responseBody)) {
    return preface + "[no body]";
  }


  if (charset == null) {
    charset = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
  }
  int maxChars = 200;


  if (responseBody.length < maxChars * 2) {
    return preface + "[" + new String(responseBody, charset) + "]";
  }


  try {
    Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(responseBody), charset);
    CharBuffer buffer = CharBuffer.allocate(maxChars);
    reader.read(buffer);
    reader.close();
    buffer.flip();
    return preface + "[" + buffer.toString() + "... (" + responseBody.length + " bytes)]";
  }
  catch (IOException ex) {
    // should never happen
    throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
  }
}
```

As you can see, this is method the one that actually truncates the message.

In order to provide the full message, you can your own provided [`ResponseErrorHandler`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/b595dc1dfad9db534ca7b9e8f46bb9926b88ab5a/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/client/ResponseErrorHandler.java#L32) implementation.

For instance, reusing the code implement in `DefaultErrorHandler`:

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpResponse;
import org.springframework.lang.Nullable;
import org.springframework.util.ObjectUtils;
import org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler;
import org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException;
import org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException;
import org.springframework.web.client.UnknownHttpStatusCodeException;

public class CustomRestTemplateResponseErrorHandler extends DefaultResponseErrorHandler {
  
  // This overloaded method version is only available since Spring 5.0
  // For previous versions of the library you can override
  // handleError(ClientHttpResponse response) instead
  @Override
  protected void handleError(ClientHttpResponse response, HttpStatus statusCode) throws IOException {
    String statusText = response.getStatusText();
    HttpHeaders headers = response.getHeaders();
    byte[] body = getResponseBody(response);
    Charset charset = getCharset(response);
    String message = getErrorMessage(statusCode.value(), statusText, body, charset);

    switch (statusCode.series()) {
      case CLIENT_ERROR:
        throw HttpClientErrorException.create(message, statusCode, statusText, headers, body, charset);
      case SERVER_ERROR:
        throw HttpServerErrorException.create(message, statusCode, statusText, headers, body, charset);
      default:
        throw new UnknownHttpStatusCodeException(message, statusCode.value(), statusText, headers, body, charset);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Return error message with details from the response body:
   * <pre>
   * 404 Not Found: [{'id': 123, 'message': 'actual mesage']
   * </pre>
   *
   * In contrast to <code>DefaultResponseErrorHandler</code>, the message will not be truncated.
   */
  private String getErrorMessage(
      int rawStatusCode, String statusText, @Nullable byte[] responseBody, @Nullable Charset charset) {

    String preface = rawStatusCode + " " + statusText + ": ";
    if (ObjectUtils.isEmpty(responseBody)) {
      return preface + "[no body]";
    }

    if (charset == null) {
      charset = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
    }

    // return the message without truncation
    return preface + "[" + new String(responseBody, charset) + "]";
  }
}
```

Then, configure `RestTemplate` to use this custom `ResponseErrorHandler`:

```java
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

@Slf4j
public class RestTemplateTest {

    @Test
    void shouldPrintErrorForRestTemplate() {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        ResponseErrorHandler errorHandler = new CustomRestTemplateResponseErrorHandler();
        restTemplate.setErrorHandler(errorHandler);

        try {
            restTemplate.getForEntity("http://hellosmilep.free.beeceptor.com/error/notfound", String.class);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Error calling REST API", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Please, see [this related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38093388/spring-resttemplate-exception-handling) or [this article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-template-error-handling) for further examples.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I have raised [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/27552) issue to Spring team for the possibility of making `maxChars` configurable in `DefaultResponseErrorHandler`.

Comment: You're welcome @Smile. That's great, well done! I definitely agree with you, I also thought about the possibility of raising a similar issue. I hope you get feedback soon and that the issue will be resolved in a future version of the framework.

Comment: Spring has removed this message size limit. I have added this update to my question. Thank you!

Comment: It is fantastic @Smile!! I am happy to hear that!!

Answer (score 1):

In place of doing an if you can catch an HttpClientErrorException, so with that you can avoid boiler plate

```
@Test
void shouldPrintErrorForRestTemplate() {
    try {

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        restTemplate.getForEntity("http://hellosmilep.free.beeceptor.com/error/notfound", String.class);

    } catch(HttpClientErrorException e) {
        log.error(e.getResponseBodyAsString(),e);
    }catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Error calling REST API", e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I can do that but I am more inclined to know why the error message is getting truncated, is there some size limit on message for truncation, if yes - how to change this limit.